# ping different ip addresses and send results in email using php

Tags: php, email, ping

im trying to make a script that will ping 11 ip addresses and then send the result on my email, but i havent done any progress at all, i looked for tutorials and i saw one where i can ping an address and i manage to make it send the result to an email, can you help me make the script ping different addressesand then send the resuls in one email.

here is the codes for the ping.

```
<?php
$Email = "kvintijam@gmail.com";

$ip = "192.168.0.100";
$ip2 = exec ("ping 192.168.0.100 ");

     mail($Email, 'result',$ip2,'From: ismaakeel@gmail.com');   

?>
```

and here is the ip that i need to ping

```
ping 192.168.2.13 > "%userprofile%\desktop\mypings1.txt"

ping 192.168.2.31 >> "%userprofile%\desktop\mypings2.txt"

ping 192.168.2.32 >> "%userprofile%\desktop\mypings3.txt"

ping 192.168.2.250 >> "%userprofile%\desktop\mypings4.txt"

ping 192.168.2.50 >> "%userprofile%\desktop\mypings5.txt"

ping 192.168.2.51 >> "%userprofile%\desktop\mypings6.txt"

ping 119.73.140.130 >> "%userprofile%\desktop\mypings7.txt"

ping 192.168.2.253 >> "%userprofile%\desktop\mypings8.txt"

ping 192.168.2.9 >> "%userprofile%\desktop\mypings9.txt"

ping 192.168.2.10 >> "%userprofile%\desktop\mypings10.txt"

ping 192.168.2.2 >> "%userprofile%\desktop\mypings11.txt"
```

hope you can help me with my problem :( thanks

Comment: Uhmm...store the results then send the mail, like, you know, with all the results...?

Comment: yes exactly like that

Answer (score 0):

```
$ipList = array("127.0.0.1", "localhost");

$content = "";
foreach($ipList as $ip)
    $content .= exec("ping " . $ip) . "<br />";

mail($Email, 'result', $content, 'From: ismaakeel@gmail.com');
```

Just switch and add the addresses in the $ipList and you good to go :).

Comment: where will i put the ip's? thanks for your help. im really new to this so sorry for a newbie questions

Comment: $ipList = array("127.0.0.1", "localhost"); Swtich this array to your IPs, 127.0.0.1 is one address and localhost is another .. this is a basic php array.

Comment: so i just need to put the IP's inside the array?

Comment: $ipList = array("127.0.0.1", "192.168.2.13","192.168.2.31","localhost") like this?

Comment: igot this error ) Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\test\send-email.php on line 13

Comment: set_time_limit(0); add it to the top of script

Comment: <?php
$Email = "kvintijam@gmail.com";

$ip = "192.168.0.100";
$ip2 = exec ("ping 192.168.0.100 ");

 $ipList = array("127.0.0.1", "localhost");

$content = "";
foreach($ipList as $ip)
    $content .= exec("ping " . $ip) . "<br />";

mail($Email, 'result', $content, 'From: ismaakeel@gmail.com');

?>

Comment: thats the whole code so far , sorry dont know how to properly post codes in the comment box, but is it right? hope you understand and thankyou very much, i really appreciated this